# how to use if-else from a function into another function

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a function 'get_number(code, attribute)' that outputs a specific section of a code that is associated with a specific piece of information. But I'm not sure how I would use this function within 'print_description(code)' so I can get the specific section of the code when the function only has one return.

Under the 'print_description(code)' docstring, I want to replace those equations 'get_number(code, attribute)'

```
def get_number(code, attribute):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns number from code and attribute.
    Use: code = get_number(code, attribute)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        code- an arbitrary code (str)
        attribute - some string representing a code attribute (str)
    Returns:
        number - value derived from attribute and serial number (int)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """

    if attribute == 'x':
        number = (int(code)) // 100000
    elif attribute == 'y':
        number = ((int(code)) // 10000) % 10
    elif attribute == 'z':
        number = ((int(code))// 1000) % 10
    elif attribute == 'info':
        number = ((int(code)) % 1000)
    else:
        number = -99
    return number 

def print_description(code):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Print detailed description based on the code.
    Use: description = print_description(code)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        code - an arbitrary serial number (str)
    Returns:
        x- x code (int)
        y- y code (int)
        z- z code (int)
        info - info code (int)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    x_code = (int(code)) // 100000
    y_code = ((int(code)) // 10000) % 10
    z_code = ((int(code))// 1000) % 10
    info_num = ((int(code)) % 1000)
     
    if not isinstance(code, str):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('{} {} {} {}'.format(x1, y1, info_num, z1))
    return
```

Comment: `def get_number(code, type):` Shouldn't that be `def get_number(code, attribute):`?

Comment: Also, maybe return all the codes in a dictionary: `return {"x_code": int(code) // 100000, "y_code": ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the function once per type, like so:

```py
country_code = get_code(serial_number, 'country')
color_code = get_code(serial_number, 'color')
size_code = get_code(serial_number, 'size')
item_num = get_code(serial_number, 'item')
```

Answer (score 0):

I completed your code, with some remarks.

```
def get_code(serial_number, type):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns code from serial number and type.
    Use: code = get_code(serial_number, type)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        serial_number - an arbitrary serial number (str)
        type - some string representing a serial number attribute (str)
    Returns:
        code - value derived from type and serial number (int)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    ....

def print_description(serial_number):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Print detailed description based on the serial number.
    Use: description = print_description(serial_number)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        serial_number - an arbitrary serial number (str)
    Returns:
        country - country code (int)
        color - color code (int)
        size - size code (int)
        item - item code (int)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    if not isinstance(serial_number, str):
        print('Invalid Serial Number')
    else:
        country_code = get_code(serial_number, 'country')
        color_code = get_code(serial_number, 'color')
        size_code = get_code(serial_number, 'size')
        item_num = get_code(serial_number, 'item')

        # where is get_country, get_color, etc., defined?
        # country1 = get_country(country_code)
        # color1 = get_color(color_code)
        # size1 = get_size(size_code)

        # There is not 'Undefined' in Python! Is this code a port from JS?
        # if country1 == 'Undefined' or color1 == 'Undefined' or size1 == 'Undefined':
        #    print('Description not found')
        #else:
        #
        print('{} {} Ball, item#: {} made in {}'.format(size_code, color_code, item_num, country_code))

    return # where are the return values?
```